# JavaFX not working after upgrade - libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 not found

Tags: java, ubuntu

I upgraded my kubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 having much troubles now. One is, that my java installation seems to be corrupted or misconfigured now.

I can't run any java apps anymore, at least none using javafx. Netbeans-8.1 couldn't be loaded after upgrade, but the reinstallation using apt-get works.

JDK path: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101/

java -jar says as expected 'java version "1.8.0_101"'

When trying to run some applications I get following errors:

```
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.


java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Desktop API is not supported on the current platform
    at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:144)


Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
```

What to do?

EDIT: after some research I tried to find the missing dependency. Its:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101/jre/lib/i386/libprism_es2.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

This file actually exists on my system: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0

Answer (score 0):

If someone else has this problem here the solution: (actually 32bit version of library was missing)

run sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386